# Installer not being updated ( probably because of Windows 7 file cache )

Tags: windows-7, cache, installer, visual-foxpro

I'm creating an installer for my Visual FoxPro application using [ISTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) and I[nno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It is ok for me for the first time.
But, I updated my code and re-built the EXE file. Then, compiled the installer again.
I found that my update was not compiled into the installer and I did not see the update in my running application.

I noticed that the EXE file, which was built by VFP, was updated properly. It seems the installation script did not output the updated file.
But, when I changed folder names, it did work. I don't want to change folder names whenever I run that installation script. It is not a good idea actually.
I think it is because of Windows 7 cache system. Mine is Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1.

For example,
My previous output file is located at C:\path\to\myinstaller.exe
When I compile the installation script, the output file there should be overwritten, but it was not as expected. Although I deleted the file, it did not work.
When I changed to output file path as C:\newpath\to\myinstaller.exe, I got the fix, but it is not a solution what I'm looking for.

Does anyone how to do that?

**[Edit]**
I found that the installed directory was not updated properly.
For example, I installed the program to C:\Program files\MyInstalledApp
When I run the installer again, that installation directory should be overwritten, but failed.
Thus, I got to uninstall the app before I re-install it.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: The problem is within your installation script. This is really a bug, not overwriting an existing file, which you should fix somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the installer should detect previous install before installation, uninstall previous installation if exist, but leave config/data file alone base on user choice. Following is a link for that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000296/innosetup-how-to-automatically-uninstall-previous-installed-version